# jQuery AJAX slower than accessing DOM element

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, registration

I want to check whether username is free for use with AJAX and jQuery.

This is the registration input field

```
      <tr> 
          <td><input type = "text" id ="new_username"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td id ="information"></td>
     </tr>
     <input type = "submit" id = "sign-up" value = "Sign up" />
```

here is the jquery part with ajax

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#new_username').blur(function() {
        var newUsername = $(this).val(); 

        $.post('../registration/check-username.php', 
            { 
                newUsername : newUsername  
            }, function (data) {
                $('#information').html(data);
            }
        );  
    }); 

    if( $("#information").html() != "" ) { 
        $("#sign-up").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else { 
        $("#sign-up").removeAttr("disabled"); 
    }     
});
})(jQuery);
```

If there's any problem - the "information" td gets some error message. If the username is free it's empty and no any notification. 
The problem is it takes some to for the ajax to response and it's faster just to click somewhere - that causes check that is not correct. Any ideas if you understand my question ?

Comment: .. you might want to try and re-clarrify ... if jquery is to slow and you want something faster javascript will improve speed slightly  if i do understand what your asking

Comment: the question is how to wait the ajax response first and after that to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `$.post` is a asynchronous request means once the request is sent to the server to verify the username the script execution will continue. In your case this means the `if` condition will get executed before the server responds, so the solution is to move the `if` condition inside the callback method.

Also it is better to use the [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method to modify the disabled property

Try

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#new_username').blur(function() {
            var newUsername = $(this).val(); 

            $.post('../registration/check-username.php', 
                   { 
                       newUsername : newUsername  
                   }, function (data) {
                       $('#information').html(data);

                       $("#sign-up").prop('disabled', data != "");
                   }
                  );  
        });         
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I clearly misinterpreted the question if this was the correct answer - I thought the issue was that the submit wasn't being disabled until the AJAX response occurred.

Comment: @RyanBrodie If you look at the code he was trying to disable the button based on the contents of `#information` element which was populated by the ajax call

Comment: I got that but assumed he would of wanted to disable that button *during* the request to prevent accidental form submission, thus explaining my use of `beforeSend` method in answer. Not to worry.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you need to wait for the AJAX response to come back. Without refactoring your code completely, just do your check once the response has returned.
You are right, you need to wait for the AJAX response to come back. Without refactoring your code completely, just do your check once the response has returned.

```
$.post('../registration/check-username.php', 
  { 
    newUsername : newUsername  
  }, function (data) {
    $('#information').html(data);
  }).done(function(){
    if( $("#information").html() != "" ) { 
      $("#sign-up").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else { 
       $("#sign-up").removeAttr("disabled"); 
    } 
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think by "it's faster just to click somewhere" you're referring to users being able to click submit before the input has been validated. Use the `$.ajax()` `beforeSend` method to get around this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#new_username').blur(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "../registration/check-username.php",
      data: {
        newUsername: $(this).val()
      },
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#sign-up").attr("disabled","disabled");
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#information').html(data);
        if( !data )
          $("#sign-up").removeAttr("disabled");
      }
    });
  });
});
```